# How to convert correctly from datetime2 data-type to small date and to elliminate HH:mm:SS.000000 padding

Tags: t-sql, date-format, data-conversion

I have created a table with a column with a date data type which correspond to a date data in yyy-MM-dd format.
In the database it presents it as if the data type is datetime2(7).
More generally all the date data-types (date, smalldate, datetime) are presented as datetime2(7) even datetime2 with less ms presicions.

[image]

I tried to execute the following query:

```
SELECT   
     CAST('2007-05-08 12:35:29. 1234567 +12:15' AS time(2)) AS 'time'   
    ,CAST('2007-05-08 12:35:29. 1234567 +12:15' AS date) AS 'date'   
    ,CAST('2007-05-08 12:35:29.123' AS smalldatetime) AS   
        'smalldatetime'   
    ,CAST('2007-05-08 12:35:29.123' AS datetime) AS 'datetime'   
    ,CAST('2007-05-08 12:35:29. 1234567 +12:15' AS datetime2(7)) AS   
        'datetime2'
```

And I displayed the following table:
[image]

Is there any management settings that stricts the date conversion or alternitavly, is there any more powerful conversion functions to display and store data in the correct data types?

Comment: Hi Sabin, I have tried the following query:

Comment: Hi Sabin, I have tried the following query:
SELECT   
     CONVERT( time(2), '2007-05-08 12:35:29. 1234567 +12:15') AS 'time'   
    ,CONVERT(date, '2007-05-08 12:35:29. 1234567 +12:15') AS 'date'   
    ,CONVERT(smalldatetime, '2007-05-08 12:35:29.123') AS   
        'smalldatetime'   
    ,CONVERT(datetime, '2007-05-08 12:35:29.123') AS 'datetime'   
    ,CONVERT(datetime2(7), '2007-05-08 12:35:29. 1234567 +12:15') AS   
        'datetime2'

And the result where the same, more over I would like to convert the column

Comment: It's not clear your question, what is the desired output ? `CONVERT/CAST` is converting  the expression to the desired data type, see here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c683db03ba733417c55d23e8674e0a32

Comment: I'm trying to convert date column to complay a specified date data-type.
From the table perspective the data-type is changed but when I display the column it is still in datetime2(7) format: yyyy-MM-ddTHH:MM:SS.0000000 even though the column is just a date

Comment: Which client are you using to run queries & display results? SSMS?

Comment: Actually I'm working with Azure Synapse